# JavaScript Equivalent Of PHP __call

Tags: javascript

In PHP you can detect when a method is called even when it doesn't exist using the "magic" `__call` function.

```
public function __call($methodName, $args)
{
    // do something
}
```

You can call any method and the name and arguments are passed to this magic catch-all.

Is there a similar technique in JavaScript that would allow any method to be called even if it actually didn't exist on the object?

```
var foo = (function () {
    return {
         __call: function (name, args) { // NOT REAL CODE
             alert(name); // "nonExistent"
         }
    }
}());

foo.nonExistent();
```

Comment: PHP can even do default handlers [for property calls](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php), not just method calls.

Comment: Hooking https://stackoverflow.com/q/2050470/632951

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It **is** possible using the ES6 [Proxy API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

```js
var myObj = {};
var myProxy = new Proxy(myObj, {
  get: function get(target, name) {
    return function wrapper() {
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
      console.log(args[0]);
      return "returns: " + args[0];
    }
  }
});
console.log(myProxy.foo('bar'));
```

Browser compatibility is available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#Browser_compatibility). As of August 2017 all browsers (including Microsoft Edge) except Internet Explorer support it.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3757676/1559840) for a more complete look at Proxy.

Comment: Minor clarification - Proxy does not allow you to emulate PHP's `__call` precisely. PHP's `__call` and `__get` distinguish between the property being invoked as a method vs accessed as a property. By contrast, Proxy merges these concepts. All this means is you can't use Proxy to selectively define properties as functions only when they are invoked as such. You would only be able to provide for ALL methods, or inspect the property name and provide functions selectively.

Answer (score 9):

**[Obsolete since Gecko 43 (Firefox 43 / Thunderbird 43 / SeaMonkey 2.40)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod)**

You can use [`__noSuchMethod__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/NoSuchMethod) in Firefox. Unfortunately it is non standard...

Related question : [Is there an equivalent of the __noSuchMethod__ feature for properties, or a way to implement it in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266789/is-there-an-equivalent-of-the-nosuchmethod-feature-for-properties-or-a-way)

Comment: Hi @rohk thanks for the answer. I am going to have to try a slightly different strategy for what I need, but the information is good. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

*To build upon @amirnissim's answer a slight bit.*

As most of us are probably already aware, [ES6 introduces the Proxy API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), which allows us to create an object (the Proxy object) that traps calls to that object, whereby we are given an opportunity to "route" the attribute the user called on the object to whatsoever we may wish.

#### Mimicking PHP's Magic Methods

There is unfortuantely no way to extend a class using the Proxy object, but what we can do is set up an intermediary step to turn an object into a proxy, and route any incoming method calls to the method available on the object itself:

```
class MyProxy
{
    constructor ()
    {
        return this.asProxy()
    }

    /**
     * Return as a proxy with this object as its target.
     */
    asProxy ()
    {
        let handler = {
            /**
             * This function is called whenever any property on the Proxy 
             * is called.
             * 
             * @param target the "parent" object; the object the proxy 
             *        virtualizes
             * @param prop the property called on the Proxy
             */
            get: function (target, prop)
            {
                /* This will return the property on the "parent" object
                 */
                if (typeof target[prop] !== 'undefined')
                    return target[prop]

                // TODO: implement custom logic
            }
        }

        return new Proxy(this, handler)
    }
}
```

This essentially gives you the same functionality to PHP's magic `__get` method and `__call` method at the same time. As for the `__call` version, we are simply returning a function for the user to enter arguments into.

#### Demonstrating the Above

In order to use this, let us first add a bit of custom logic to the place where the `TODO: implement custom logic` resides:

```
if (prop === 'helloWorld')
    return function () { console.log("Hello, world!") }
else
    return function () { console.log("Where art thou, hello world?") }
```

If we then go ahead and create a new instance of the `MyProxy` class, we can trigger the custom logic we implemented:

```
let myProxy = new MyProxy()

myProxy.test()
myProxy.hello()
myProxy.helloWorld()
```

The above example outputs:

> `Where art thou, hello world?`
>   `Where art thou, hello world?`
>   `Hello, world!`

It would, of course, also be possible to return any other type of value from the `get` function, we could just as well return a string or an integer.

#### Ease of Use; Usage Through Inheritance

In order to make this even easier to use, may I suggest wrapping the `asProxy` method into another class, then simply extending any class that needs the "magic method" functionality with the class containing the `asProxy` method? By simply returning the `asProxy` method from the constructor, you are basically given the same functionality you would see in PHP, in JavaScript.

Of course, it would also be somewhat required that the `get method` is somewhat editable so that custom logic can still be handled from the subclass. Perhaps by sending in a closure to the `return this.asProxy(() => {})` that is then called from the `get` function itself? Or perhaps even route the `get` function to a `get` method present on the `target` object?

Do keep in mind, however, this is only ever applicable in ES6. [Transpilers such as Babel](https://babeljs.io/) cannot, [and I quote](http://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#proxies):

> Due to the limitations of ES5, Proxies cannot be transpiled or polyfilled.

The solution presented above does however work perfectly fine as long as this condition is met. It is, for instance, a perfectly viable option in [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Answer (score 3):

No. Due to the way JavaScript works, the equivalent would be like Python's `__getattr__`/`__getitem__`, rather than PHP's `__call`, as it would need to be dealt with when retrieving the attribute rather than when calling it.

Then, you can look at a question like [Python's __getattr__ in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441005/pythons-getattr-in-javascript) which answers it in that way.

See also such questions as these:

- [JavaScript's equivalent to PHP's __get() magic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959187/javascripts-equivalent-to-phps-get-magic-method)
- [JavaScript getter for all properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994143/javascript-getter-for-all-properties)

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not an elegant way as we've already deduced that JavaScript does not have a `__call`, `method_missing`, `__getattr__` it is possible to create combinations of properties to create concrete functions that relay to a single method, passing along the properties that were used to create it.

One example is [Myriad.js](https://github.com/Wildhoney/Myriad.js).