# In the Proxy handler, how to distiguish getting a property (var) vs calling a method?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code, where I'm using Proxy object (proxy) to try to catch method calls and access of the properties:

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/r8j4fzxL/2/

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    console.clear();

    //some empty class where I want to trap methods props
    class X {
        //...
    }

    let proxy = {
        get: function(target, prop, receiver) {

            console.log('get called: ',
                'target:', target,
                'prop:', prop,
                'receiver:', receiver
            );
            //this is OK, if we are called as a method.
            //but it isn't when called as .prop - because, obviously, we return a function here.
            return function(...args) {
                console.log('wrapper args:', args);
                return 42;
            }
        },


    };


    let p1 = new Proxy(X, proxy);
    //how to distinguish the two in the above proxy:
    console.log(p1.test('some arg passed'));
    console.log(p1.test);
})();
```

And I have two questions here.

1. Generally, is this the right way, if I want to trap both properties access and method access? Or maybe should I go with .apply trap somehow (failed to do so though)?
2. If this is the right way (using .get) - then how do I know how the user accessed the... thing? Via `.foo;` or via `.foo()`;?

Resources I used and apparently didn't fully understand:

- [MDN docs: Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)
- [MDN docs: handler.get()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get)
- [MDN docs: handler.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/apply)

SO: [JavaScript Equivalent Of PHP __call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226064/javascript-equivalent-of-php-call)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually a solution for this question (which was marked as duplicate of this but is not !!): [How to get function arguments in a Proxy handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091127/how-to-get-function-arguments-in-a-proxy-handler)

You cannot get the arguments in a "get" trap, because when the get trap is called the functions is not called yet!
But you can create another proxy with "apply" trap, here is the example:

```js
(function () {
  "use strict";
  console.clear();

  //some empty class where I want to trap methods & props
  class X {}

  let proxy = {
    get: function (target, prop, receiver) {
      console.log(arguments); //this gives the arguments of the 'get' trap itself.

      // normally you trap an existent funcion, in this example we are creating a new one here
      var F = function (...args) {
        console.log("Original function call", args);
      };

      return new Proxy(F, {
        apply: function (target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
          // here you have the arguments
          console.log("Trapped function call", argumentsList);
          return target.apply(thisArg, argumentsList);
        },
      });
    },
  };

  let p = new Proxy(X, proxy);
  console.log(p.test("some arg passed"));
})();
```

So the trick is to trap the function with get first, and instead of returning the original function, to return a Proxy with apply trap to the original function.

Comment: ah, wow, that's pretty smart :) Thanks! And yeah, thanks for noticing that the other question isn't a duplicate :)

Answer (score 3):

Proxies are essentially objects that expose a programmatic way to hook into the operations that objects can have performed on them. With that as a base, there is no way to distinguish a property access from a property access + call, at the point where the property is accessed. The fact that the returned value is a function is all that you can know.

From the standpoint of the language, `p.foo()` breaks down into

```
var p = ...
var foo = p.foo;
foo.apply(p, []);
```

as an example. `p.foo` wouldn't actually access `.apply`, but the point is that the property access is entirely independent of how the returned value is actually used/called.

So you option would essentially be to check whether the value of `test` was already a function, and if so, wrap that value with your wrapper. If it was not a function, it seems like you'll want to skip wrapping it. e.g.

```
get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
  var value = Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
  if (typeof value === "function") {
    return function(...args) {
      // probably call 'value' with whatever you need
    };
  } else {
    // return the origin value.
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand. But, just to understand it in 100% :) - if the *target* doesn't have  the `test` at all, my mission is just... impossible?

Comment: If it doesn't have a value, you could hard-code it to be a function based on the name "test". You'd never want a property that was sometimes a function and sometimes not. The type of a property shouldn't change based on how the property is used, that would be super confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another snippet using get trap

```js
const car = {
   color: 'blue',
   schema: "xlm"
}

const handler = {
   get(target, property) {
           console.log( property );
           console.log( target[property] ?? 'Not found' );
           return new Proxy ( ( ...args ) => {
              console.log( "args:" + args );
              return proxyObject;
           },
           { 
              get( _, innerProperty ){
                 console.log( "innerProperty", innerProperty);
                 return proxyObject[innerProperty];
              }
           })
         }
      }

let proxyObject = new Proxy(car, handler);
proxyObject.color.schema(8).not.be('red');
```